# X509_get0_notBefore and X509_get0_noAfter in this scope?

Tags: c++, c, openssl

I'm trying to get the expiration date for the digital certificates. I'm using sample code from this lab. http://www.cis.syr.edu/~wedu/seed/Labs_12.04/Crypto/Crypto_PublicKey/

```
  /* We could do all sorts of certificate verification stuff here before
     deallocating the certificate. */
  int i;
  //expir = X509_get0_notBefore(server_cert);
  i = X509_cmp_time(X509_get0_notBefore(server_cert), ptime);
  i = X509_cmp_time(X509_get0_notAfter(server_cert), ptime);
  //printf("expiration date: %d",i);
```

and it keeps giving me this error:

```
cli.cpp:122:52: error: ‘X509_get0_notBefore’ was not declared in this scope
cli.cpp:123:51: error: ‘X509_get0_notAfter’ was not declared in this scope
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

and here are the header files from the sample code I'm using.

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <memory.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <netdb.h>

#include <openssl/crypto.h>
#include <openssl/x509.h>
#include <openssl/pem.h>
#include <openssl/ssl.h>
#include <openssl/err.h>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems for your OpenSSL version you should do

```
i = X509_cmp_time(server_cert->validity->notBefore, ptime);
i = X509_cmp_time(server_cert->validity->notAfter, ptime);
```